# Changing time format from 9:00am to 09:00am in php

Tags: php

Iam having variable with value 9:30 am - 12:00 pm i.e

```
       $val=$shift (o/p 9:30 am - 12:00pm)
```

I want to convert it to 09:30 am - 12:00pm, i mean i need to add 0 infront of number if time having one digit

Comment: Search for Zero padding dates in php

Comment: @Nadh You mean it saves as a string in the database? with this format `9:30 am - 12:00pm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are saving your time in your database as a string as `9:30 am - 12:00pm` you can just split them. Then format each data.

```
$val= "9:30 am - 12:00pm";
$splittedString = explode('-', $val);

$time1 = date('h:ia',strtotime($splittedString[0]));
$time2 = date('h:ia',strtotime($splittedString[1]));

echo $time1." - ".$time2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `date` function then you can format time using `h`.

For example

```
echo date('h:ia'); // output 09:50am
```

See [Referance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

If you have values from DataBase as you mentioned in comment then you need to apply PHP's built-in function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) before formatting the time.

For Example

```
echo date( 'h:ia', strtotime('9:30 am') ); // output 09:50am
```

Comment: my value is coming like this , i need to change this value only to 09:30 am - 12:00pm..I mean how to give h:i:a to 09:30 am - 12:00pm this format

Comment: From where you are getting values?

Comment: How you store values to database? can you share screenshot ? Both values are from different fields or from same field?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo date('h:ia',strtotime("9:30 am"))." - ".date('h:ia',strtotime("12:00pm"));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.